# PowerShell: How to copy only ".exe" file from ZIP folder to another folder

Tags: powershell

I have a "ZIP" file and when we extract this, we have 1 "EXE" file within 4-5 sub folder depth level.

I would like to grab that "EXE" file and copy into another folder. How to do it using PowerShell?

I tried below, but it will copy all the ZIP content,

```
 $shell = New-Object -ComObject shell.application
 $zip = $shell.NameSpace("Source Path")
 foreach ($item in $zip.items()) {
   $shell.Namespace("Destination Path").CopyHere($item)
}
```

Comment: 1) Extract zip file to some directory; 2) Use `Get-ChildItem` with `-Filter` and `-Recurse` to locate .exe file; 3) pipe to `Copy-Item` and specify destination.

Comment: If you don't extract the entire zip file you'll probably need to create a function that you can call recursively to crawl through folders within the zip to be able to find the exe file in order to extract only that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simple snippet should get your job done**

```
#Sets the variable to the Source folder, recurse drills down to folders within

$Source = get-childitem "C:\Users" -recurse   #"C:\Users" an example

#Filters by extension .exe
$List = $Source | where {$_.extension -eq ".exe"}

#Copies all the items to the specified destination
$List | Copy-Item -Destination "C:\Scripts"   #"C:\Scripts" an example
```

---

**The module above scans for every single .EXE files within C:\Users* and copies them to C:\Scripts**

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, Clint's answer did not work for me, but something based on [Extract Specific Files from ZIP Archive](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/extract-specific-files-from-zip-archive) does, with a variation to target a specifically named file. Will need a further tweak to handle multiple files sharing the same name.

Code:

```
# Set source zip path, target output directory and file name filter

$ZipPath = 'C:\temp\Test.zip'
$OutDir = 'C:\temp'
$Filter = 'MyExe.exe'

# Load compression methods
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem

# Open zip file for reading
$Zip = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead($Path)

# Copy selected items to the target directory
$Zip.Entries | 
    Where-Object { $_.FullName -eq $Filter } | 
    ForEach-Object { 
        # Extract the selected items from the zip archive
        # and copy them to the out folder
        $FileName = $_.Name
        [System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::ExtractToFile($_, "$OutDir\$FileName", $true)
    }

# Close zip file
$Zip.Dispose()
```